# Selected date = the name selected data does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I'm creating an asp.net application and I've used the following code:

```
Application["getData"] = new GigOpportunity(txtId.Text, 
                                            Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedData),
                                            txtVenue.Text, 
                                            txtGenre.Text, 
                                            Convert.ToDouble(txtCost.Text), 
                                            Convert.ToInt32(txtCapacity.Text), 
                                            chkHeadliner.Checked, 
                                            txtMainAct.Text, 
                                            chkEngineer.Checked);
```

But when I run the form and select okay it says:

> "Input String was not in the correct format"

And when I look further under the selecteddata variable it says:

> "SelectedDate = The name 'SelectedData' does not exist in the current context"

This is where SelectedData comes from:

```
string SelectedData = dateTimePicker.SelectedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Comment: is it Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedData) or Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedDate) ?

Comment: This is where SelectedData comes from: string SelectedData = dateTimePicker.SelectedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");

Comment: you still didn't answer my question right! is it 'SelectedData' or 'SelectedDate'?

Comment: Sorry and yeah it's (SelectedData).

Comment: Please try DateTime.Parse method instead of Convert.ToDateTime

Comment: Tried and it didn't work, I know it's probably an amateur mistake I've made I just can't see it.

Comment: Same as before, "Input string was not in the correct format"

Comment: can you try DateTime.ParseExact(SelectedData, "dd MMMM yyyy", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); ?

Comment: the problem is say if you have selected today's date from date picker, SelectedDAta will be '30 April 2014' and youa re trying to convert this into datetime

Answer (score -1):

If you already have the date time why not just use it and pass it to GigOppurtunity?

edit after new information

the error that you are getting is usually caused by using a variable that has not been declared.
I believe that GigOppurtunity has a typo in its constructor. Check the constructor and see if the parameter names are correct.

I would say in the constructor the parameter is selecteddate 
and when it is being set it says

```
 this.selecteddate = selecteddata
```

it should say

```
this.selecteddate = selecteddate
```

Comment: Just because it should be sent with everything else, I wouldn't like to pass everything across separately though I suppose I could do it that way it just seems like this way should work as well.

Comment: Just above in the same method, using string SelectedData = dateTimePicker.SelectedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see if it was breaking when SelectedData was set or when it was being converted in the GigOppurtunity constructor

Comment: also could you show us the full method and the section of the form that datepicker is being declared

Comment: When it was being converted is when I used the debugger.

Comment: what is the value of selecteddata when it tries to convert

Comment: It's a string at first then I try to convert it to DateTime, it gets the value but still has the error?